# Best way to represent a ladder in a database

Tags: algorithm, sorting, database-design

I have a requirement to represent ladder results, that were previously kept in an excel sheet, on a website.

The players on the ladder don't have scores. If player A beat player B, player A's going to be placed above player B in the ladder.

My problem is the following:
Let's say I have 5 players, ranked as follows:

1. Player 1
2. Player 2
3. Player 3
4. Player 4
5. Player 5

If Player 5 beat Player 1, Player 5 now moves on the top of the ladder. If the player order is decided on the ranking number I have to update the ranking number of all players between those who actually played which just sounds wrong to me.

I had an idea of assigning scores to each player, if Player A beats Player B then Player A gets Player B's score + 1, then the ranking is score in descending order. This works reasonably well up to the point when players end up on the same score. I can get around that too with adding a "LastUpdated" field in the database so whichever score got last updated goes below the other (the LastUpdated player hasn't actually beaten the player on the same score, they were just moved up there). This then fails at the point when a person does multiple adjustments on the same day so multiple players end up on the same score and the ranking order purely depends on which player got updated last. This is a problem as there's a requirement for the admin to be able to move players up and down freely. It also makes it impossible to add a player between players that have the same score (the winning player would have to jump the whole group).

My last resort would be to get the current ranking order from the database, put it all in a table, allow the admin to freely move players wherever they want, then have a single save operation that would get the current ranking of all the players and update everybody. This sounds horribly wrong though.

There are about 160 players in the ladder so the operation wouldn't be particularly lengthy, just sounds wrong.

So, what would the best way to change ranking order and get it saved in the database be?

Answer (score 2):

If your database support exact numeric data types, it can be easily solved by having the ranking column an exact numeric.
Then when player 5 beat player 2, all you have to do is set player 5's rank between player 2's and player 1's. since it's an exact numeric your limit is the precision limit of the data type of choice.

Sample data:

```
id    name       rank
1.    Player 1   1.0  
2.    Player 2   2.0  
3.    Player 3   3.0  
4.    Player 4   4.0
5.    Player 5   5.0
```

Now player 5 beat player 2. so all you have to do is set it's rank to 1.5, that's between player 2's rank and the first rank higher then player 2's. 
If player 4 would beat player 1, I would set it's rank to 0.5, since player 1 has no one ranked higher.

Comment: I'd use large integers, like 1,000,000 through 5,000,000 for the initial scoring, but otherwise, a good solution.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc It's basically the same, just easier to read, I think.

Comment: A nice approach but what happens if Player 5 beats player 2 (player 5's rank is now 1.5) then Player 4 beats player 2 as well (Player 4's rank is then 1.5 as well?) then player 3 beats Player 5 - is his rank now 1.4, jumping straight over Player 4?

Comment: No, player 4's rank will be half way between player 2's rank and the next higher rank, meaning it should be 1.75 (between 2.0 of player 2 and 1.5 of player 5). This way you should not get any players with the same rank. when player 3 beats player 5, his rank should go between 1.5 and 1.0, so it should be 1.25. That's assuming I understand the way your rank should be calculated.